# MySQL duplicate entry but there are no duplicates

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Duplicate entry '(770) 633-367' for key 'phone' SQL:INSERT INTO phones(phone) VALUES("(770) 633-3679")
```

But if I select the number "(770) 633-3679" from the phones table, I'm getting empty result. I'm thinking it's probably because "(770) 633-367" and "(770) 633-3679" only differ by 1 number, the last digit. How can I force mysql to insert the said number?

Comment: Please can you give me the constrains you impose on this phones table

Comment: increase column size like `phone VARCHAR(20)`

Comment: There are only 2 fields. phone_id and phone. phone_id is auto-increment and primary id @AnikIslamAbhi